# Use a variable in Mongo JavaScript in Find

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to use a variable in a js script as below to retrieve lines processed at a certain date.
I try to define "obj_start_date" and "obj_end_date" but i'm not able to use the value in the request ....

I've already tried to find a way in the forum but nothing work for me ... thanks in advance if you can help me :)

```
var result = 0;

var obj_start_date = {};
var start_date = "2016-01-04 00:00:00";
obj_start_date[start_date]=1;

var obj_end_date = {};
var end_date  = "2016-01-04 23:59:59";
obj_end_date[end_date]=1;

var linkNames = db.lines.find({$and:[{'type':{$in:['mobile','voip']}},{'process_time':{$gte:obj_start_date}},{'process_time':{$lte:obj_end_date}}]}).map(function(doc){
  result = result + parseFloat(doc.duration);
});

print( result+ "\r\n");
```

Comment: Hi @yann! Can you plz help me understand why are you creating that `obj_end_date`? I'm not 100% sure but I think you can do something like `{'process_time':{$gte: start_date}},{'process_time':{$lte: end_date}}` so instead of using `obj_start_date`

Answer (score 2):

You could simply construct proper date objects to use in the query if the field `process_time` is a mongo date:

```
var result = 0,
    start_date = new Date("2016-01-04 00:00:00"),
    end_date = new Date("2016-01-04 23:59:59");

db.lines.find({
    "type": {
        "$in": ['mobile','voip']
    },
    "process_time": {
        "$gte": start_date,
        "$lte": end_date
    }
}).forEach(function(doc){
    result = result + parseFloat(doc.duration);
});

print( result+ "\r\n" );
```

Or using the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "type": {
                "$in": ['mobile','voip']
            },
            "process_time": {
                "$gte": start_date,
                "$lte": end_date
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null
            "total_duration": { "$sum": "$duration" }
        }
    }
]

var linkNames = db.lines.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
if (linkNames.length > 0) { printjson (linkNames[0].total_duration); }
```